# How to publish some default pages in Multisite creation?

Tags: multisite, customization, pages

In multi site environment, I need to publish some pages by default while creating a new site , is this possible?

Comment: Please define "share". :)

Comment: I found the Solution 
  [1]: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71863/wp-multisite-adding-pages-on-blog-creation-by-default

Answer (score 1):

I have done this before using WPMUDEV's [New Blog Templates plugin](https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/new-blog-template/). It allows you to create a blog template that new sites use. You can choose theme, plugins, and pages and posts I believe by creating a template site and then editing it according to your needs.

Good luck,
Z